# Use Tfrecord to feed multi-input neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tfrecord, image-classification

I have a dataset on Tfrecord that includes images and tabular data, I want to feed those data into a mixed neural network data. I saw examples of how to use multi-input neural network by using numpy arrays

```
model.fit([X_images,X_tabular],[Y_images,Y_tabular])
```

but transforming Tfrecord dataset into a numpy array by iterating slows down the process.
Is there a way to train it directly on the Tfrecord data. So far I have a model that train only an images and this is the code that I am using

```
tfrecords_schema = {
    'id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'y_label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    'x_1': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'x_2': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'x_3': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'x_4': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
}
def _parse_function(example_proto):  
    parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, tfrecords_schema)
    return parsed_example['image'], parsed_example['y_label']

    
def _parse_error(image, label):
    return image != b''


def _preprocess_function(image, label):    
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (299, 299))
    label = label_decoder(label)
    return image, label

train_data = (
    train_data
    .map(_parse_function)
    .filter(_parse_error)
    .map(_preprocess_function)
    .apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
)
validation_data = (
    validation_data
    .map(_parse_function)
    .filter(_parse_error)
    .map(_preprocess_function)
    .apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
)
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_data = train_data.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
validation_data = validation_data.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
def make_model(image_shape, num_classes):
    
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=image_shape)
    x = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input(inputs)

    base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = False
    x = base_model(x, training=False)

    global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    x = global_average_layer(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

    prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
    outputs = prediction_layer(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model = make_model(IMAGE_SHAPE, NUM_CLASSES)

learning_rate = 0.0001

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="tf/pvc_data/tmp/weights.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
]
history = model.fit(
    train_data, epochs=1, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=validation_data
)
```

Comment: You just have to make the data returned by the `tf.data.Dataset` corresponds to the input, i.e make it return `(x_image,x_tabular),(y_image,y_tabular)`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. so far I parse the tfrecord and return
return image, x_tabular, label 
instead of 
return image, label
the problem is that one I fit my model to train_data, it doesn't recognize the two inputs and the output. can you develop your answer, please ? thanks a lot

Comment: Actually I needed to pass the input as a dictionary nary, it solved my problem thanks a lot !